# Updating field in MySQL to get remove blank lines

Tags: mysql, regex

I am currently writing a query to update fields using MySQL to remove blank lines in the field. I am trying to filter this where the number of blank lines is greater than 2. I have tried this a few different ways now but none have succeeded.

My query is as follows:

```
UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(REPLACE(field, '\r', ''), '\n', '') WHERE '\n' > 2;
```

At the moment it does not appear to filter the empty lines that are less than 2.
Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: think about what `WHERE '\n' > 2;` means - does it match your desired condition?

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE field LIKE '%\n%\n%\n%'` will find lines with at least 3 newlines.

`REPLACE()` replaces all occurrences; do you really want that?